# G++ command throws "expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction"

Tags: c++, g++, c++17

Function foo takes a vector of strings. It's defined as

```
bool foo(vector<string>& input);
```

When I call foo with:

```
foo(vector<string>{"abc"});
```

my compiler gives the following error:

```
error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
```

and points to `{` as the start of the error. This compiles fine in Xcode but I get the error when running the following via command line with:

```
g++ -o -std=c++17 main.cpp
```

What is wrong with my g++ syntax?

G++ Version Information:

```
g++ --version                   
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: I can't replicate the error: see [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea5af57e1fcd6159) Instead of describing your code please provide a [mre]. Should be only a few lines in this case.

Comment: This should work in simple use-case. something you don't tell us. E.g. `foo` might be an incorrectly designed  macro and not a function.

Comment: Here is the prototype of foo: `bool foo(vector<string>& input);`

Comment: Please add that information to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: Change your parameter type to `const` to accept `rvalues`, temporaries cannot bind to `non-const lvalues references`

Comment: Even after changing foo to: `bool foo(const vector<string>& input);` the error remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command line specifies that the output file ("-o") should be called "-std=c++17" – it does not say anything about the language version, so you're compiling as C++03.
Remove the "-o" or add an actual file name.

Also, note that your "g++" is an alias for clang.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. The working command is: `g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and tried to compile it. For me there was rather problem with trying to pass non const value to function. I changed function argument to const and it compiled and printed without any problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool foo(const std::vector<std::string>& v) {
    for (auto& a : v) { std::cout << a << std::endl; } 
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    bool result = foo(std::vector<std::string> {"1", "2", "3" });
    // do something with result
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled on: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Comment: Thank you but @molbdnilo has the correct solution. My g++ arguments were incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Function `foo` expects for an l-value.

You are generating an instance and passing it to the function. But lifetime of the object is not enough for the pass-by-reference call.

Here is an example below; instance of class A is immediately destructed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A {
  public:
  A(int m): m(m) {
    cerr << __func__ << endl;
  }
  ~A() {
    cerr << __func__ << endl;
  }
  int m;
};

int main() {
  cerr << __func__ << endl;
  A(5);
  cerr << __func__ << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
main
A
~A
main
```

Comment: You sould explain why this works and OP's code doesn't (But OP's code actually works)

Comment: I did try this and the error changes to:  `error: expected expression` and still points to `{` as the starting place of the error.

Comment: `bool foo(vector<string>& input);`

Comment: You are passing rvalue to the function, but foo waiting for a reference type.

Comment: @snan I believe I am passing the correct type because the vector is created in memory before foo runs. Remember, this does compile and run fine within Xcode so I think the error is in my G++ syntax.

Comment: This is clang build output. main.cpp:7:6: note: candidate function not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument